# Edit Slide/ Page number of a PowerPoint file programatically

Tags: python, win32com, python-pptx, comtypes

I have a presentation having slide number 3, as the starting number. How can I change the number to 1. [Here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd6Jr.png)

Comment: Can you rephrase the question so it's clear what you are asking please?

Comment: rephrased and added supporting image

Comment: @scanny Can you help with this

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this programmatically, vs. changing it in PPT after the fact? It looks like the original file you're inserting objects into must have "3" set as the starting number.